# VS code intellisense C# installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I need help installing IntelliSense for C# in VS Code. I tried googling but haven't found any good answer to my question. Is there a option or extension or something in VS code that i can use to install Intellisense for C# on it. I also cant't use Visual studio because I'm on Linux.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The C# extension should include everything you need to get started including IntelliSense: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp

For Unity development, which uses Mono, you should also use the Mono extension as noted in the C# extension documentation: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.mono-debug

Comment: I need it for Unity

Comment: If you are doing your C# coding in VS Code, regardless of whether or not you are writing it for Unity, this should work. However, for debugging you may additionally need the Mono extension.

Comment: For some reason it doesnt work for  me

Comment: Can you provide more details into what doesn't work for you? Does the extension fail to install? Is there some feature of the extension you're expecting to work but doesn't?

Comment: It just doesn't show me intellisense when i type and i have to type by my own